# Swift iOS Firebase -How to Combine a queryOrdered(byChild) and GeoFire observe(.keyEntered) to get a snapshot and location result at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uisearchcontroller, geofire

Using an `UISearchController` if I want to perform a search for a user's favorite book who's title is Harry Potter I would do the following to get a snapshot it:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    // the searchText the user entered is Harry Potter
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() else { return }

    let favoriteBooksRef = Database.database().reference().child("searchFavoriteBooks").queryOrdered(byChild: "titleLowercased").queryStarting(atValue: searchText).queryEnding(atValue: searchText+"\u{f8ff}")

    favoriteBooksRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        ...
    })
}
```

If I wanted to search for users in a certain location I would perform the following with `GeoFire`:

```
let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("users_locations")
let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
let center = CLLocation(latitude: myLat, longitude: myLon)

let circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: center, withRadius: 5)

var queryHandler = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
       ...
})
```

**How can I use a UISearchController to combine both queries so that I can get a snapshot of all the users with a favorite book title of Harry Potter all within 5 kil of where I'm at?**

According [to this link](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/101#issuecomment-352689686) the person says to just add a third parameter as a snapshot in the `GFQueryResultBlock` but it doesn't explain how that snapshot reaches into a different node to pull data from.

My database (it shows 1 user but there may 20 users in the vicinity who will appear in the search results):

```
-root
   |
   @--users
   |    |
   |    @---uid789
   |          |
   |          |--username: "avidBookReader"
   |          |--lat: 34.111
   |          |--lon: -34.222
   |          @---postId001
   |                  |
   |                  |--title: "Harry Potter"
   |
   @--users_location
   |    |
   |    @---uid789
   |          |
   |          |--g: xyz234
   |          @--l:      
   |              |--0: 34.111
   |              |--1: -34.222
   |
   @--searchFavoriteBooks
        |
        @---postId001
               |
               |--uid: "uid789"
               |--titleLowercased: "harry potter"
               |--lat: 34.111
               |--lon: -34.222
```

What I tried so far. I basically first checked for all the users closest to the device then put them in an array named `usersInRadius`. After that I checked ran the query on the text entered in the search bar and added those results to an array named `favoriteBooks`. I casted them both as a `Set` and unsuccessfully tried to compare the items contained in them using the Set's `.intersection()` function and I get a warning

> Result of call to 'intersection' is unused

I then put the final results from that function into an array named `finalResults` to display in the collectionView.

The search works and I get the Harry Potter books from the `finalResults` array but the filtering for users close to me doesn't filter every one out. I think the problem happens here on step 19:

```
favoriteBooksAsSet.intersection(usersInRadiusAsSet) // I get the warning message above
```

It's filtering incorrectly. Here's the code below.

```
let radius: Double = 5.0
let usersInRadius = [SearchModels] // an arr of all the users in the vicinity 
let favoriteBooks = [SearchModels] // an arr of all the results that contain the searchText
let finalResults = [SearchModels] // the final array that will display the results of the users in the vicinity with the search text by comparing the 2 above arrays as Sets

// 1. user enters text into the searchBar
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    // 2. the text is Harry Potter
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased() else { return }

    // 3. look for all the users in the devices proximity
    getAlltheUsersInTheChosenRadius(radius: radius, searchText: searchText)
} 

func getAlltheUsersInTheChosenRadius(radius: Double, searchText: String) {

    // 4. check for location authorization
    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() ==  .authorizedAlways) {

        currentLocation = locationManager.location

        // 5. get the device's lat and lon
        let myLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let myLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude

        // 6. use them to create a CLLocation
        let center = CLLocation(latitude: myLat, longitude: myLon)

        // 7. create the geoFire node to search on
        let geofireRef = Database.database().reference().child("users_location")
        let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)

        // 7. center in a 5 meter radius
        let circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: center, withRadius: radius)

        // 8. get the .keyEntered info
        let queryHandler = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: {
            (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

            // 9. create a SearchModel object and set the key to the userId's key and the location to the location
            let searchModel = SearchModel()
            searchModel.userId = key
            searchModel.location = location

            // 10. append these objects to an array of all the users who are in the vicinity      
            self.usersInRadius.append(searchModel)
        })

        // 11. geoFire is done now query the searchText
        circleQuery.observeReady({

            self.queryTheSearchFavoriteBooksNode(searchText: searchText)
        })
    }
}

func queryTheSearchFavoriteBooksNode(searchText: searchText) {

    // 12. set the ref for the searchFavoriteBooks to search on
    let favoriteBooksRef = Database.database().reference().child("searchFavoriteBooks").queryOrdered(byChild: "titleLowercased").queryStarting(atValue: searchText).queryEnding(atValue: searchText+"\u{f8ff}")

    favoriteBooksRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            self.finalResults.removeAll()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            return
        }

        // 14. grab all the key/values pairs that have a value named "harry potter"
        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in

            guard let dict = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            // 15. init a SearchModel with the values from the dict
            let searchModel = SearchModel(dict: dict)

            // 16. check if the result is in the favoriteBooks array
            let isContained = self.favoriteBooks.contains(where: { (post) -> Bool in
                return searchModel.userId == post.userId
            })

            // 17. if it's not in the favoriteBooks array the append it to it
            if !isContained {
                self.favoriteBooks.append(searchModel)

                if self.favoriteBooks.count > 1 {

                    // 18. if there is more then 1 item in the favoriteBooks then cast it as a Set and also cast the userInRadius from step 10 as a Set
                    let favoriteBooksAsSet = Set(self.favoriteBooks)
                    let usersInRadiusAsSet = Set(self.usersInRadius)

                    // 19. compare the items in both sets and remove what I don't want. This ISN'T working
                   favoriteBooksAsSet.intersection(usersInRadiusAsSet)

                    // 20. append the results from the favoriteBooksAsSet in step 19 to the final finalResults which should display the UISearchController's results
                    self.finalResults.append(contentsOf: Array(favoriteBooksAsSet))
                }
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        })
    })
}

// this is the SearchModel
class SearchModel: : Equatable, Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int {
        guard let uid = userId, let loc = location else {
            return Int(arc4random())
        }
        return uid.djb2hash ^ loc.hashValue
    }

    var postId: String?
    var title: String?
    var userId: String?
    var location: CLLocation?
    var lat: CLLocationDegrees?
    var lon: CLLocationDegrees?

    convenience init(dict: [String: Any]) {
        self.init()

        postId = dict["postId"] as? String
        title = dict["title"] as? String
        userId = dict["userId"] as? String
        location = dict["location"] as? CLLocation
        lat = dict["lat"] as? CLLocationDegrees
        lon = dict["lon"] as? CLLocationDegrees
    }

    static func == (lhs: SearchModel, rhs: SearchModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.userId == rhs.userId
    }
}

// String extension for the hash value in the SearchModel
extension String {
    var djb2hash: Int {
        let unicodeScalars = self.unicodeScalars.map { $0.value }
        return unicodeScalars.reduce(5381) {
            ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ Int($1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the [answer from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32925620/4833705)

The problem was in my separation of the Sets on steps 18 and 19:

```
// 18. if there is more then 1 item in the favoriteBooks then cast it as a Set and also cast the userInRadius from step 10 as a Set
let favoriteBooksAsSet = Set(self.favoriteBooks)
let usersInRadiusAsSet = Set(self.usersInRadius)

// 19. compare the items in both sets and remove what I don't want. This ISN'T working
favoriteBooksAsSet.intersection(usersInRadiusAsSet)

// 20. append the results from the favoriteBooksAsSet in step 19 to the final finalResults which should display the UISearchController's results
self.finalResults.append(contentsOf: Array(favoriteBooksAsSet))
            }
```

The correction solution was to use what was from the SO answer and combine both arrays as Sets then whatever the results are from the intersection method use that to put into step 20:

```
// steps 18 and 19 combined
let tempSet = Set(self.favoriteBooks).intersection(Set(self.usersInRadius))

// 20. append the results from the tempSet in step 18 and 19 to the final finalResults which should display the UISearchController's results
self.finalResults.append(contentsOf: Array(tempSet))
```